# Is there a way to target all img tags with 0x0 size and remove them in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to upload and delete pictures in my app but sometime when I delete my pictures it keeps replacing it with an img with height and width of 0. I was wondering if there was a way to use jQuery to target all imgs with 0x0 dimensions and remove them only.

Comment: Could someone explain why I am getting so many down votes?

Comment: Do you have any code that you can add to your question?  Currently it's written asking users to write everything for you.

Comment: I was asking if this was possible and if so maybe obtain a link to a reference to research. When I googled the question I wasn't able to find any good examples so I thought it would be best if I asked on SO and try to get a reference. I solved the bug already though so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $('#imageid'); 

var width = img.width();
var height = img.height();
```

are the dimensions of the image how it is seen in browser, because `.width();` and `.height();` return DOM properties, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly:

```
$("img").filter(function() {
    return $(this).height() == 0 && $(this).width() == 0;
}).remove();
```